# Disable click event in inside nodes of li

Tags: jquery, html

here is the sample code

```
<li onclick="func1();">
    <img onclick="func2();" src='test.png' />
</li>
```

the when img was clicked the func1 is being called i want to overcome that and call func2 function , when clicked on img tag with use of jquery

Answer (score 2):

Try `return false` to prevent propagation:

```
function func2() {
    // ...

    return false;
}
```

If you would bind your events the "jQuery way", you could also use `event.stopPropagation`:

```
$('img').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    //...
});
```

Comment: i have some important code to run in func2 so i cannot return false

Comment: after stopPropagation can i continue writing code that will work ?

Comment: If you want to use `stopPropagation`, you need to bind your handlers using js instead of doing inline event handlers like you're currently doing.

Comment: Haha, it's not a miracle. Events bubble. When you click a child element, you are also clicking its parents.

Comment: I know that, but here return statement is added on img so how will that stop calling the func1 . ?